# Add in rows to matrices in a list so that all have uniform number of rows in the same order

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, data-wrangling

I have many matrices that all have the same column names but different numbers of rows. I would like them all to be uniform length, and have the rows be ordered in consecutive increasing order by the first column. See two examples of matrices that need alteration below:

```
     count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
[1,]     0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0
[2,]     1 1 1 4 0 1 0 1 0
[3,]     2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
[4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
[5,]     4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
[6,]     5 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
[7,]     8 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

     count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
[1,]     0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0
[2,]     1 1 1 4 0 1 0 1 0
[3,]     2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
[4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
[5,]     4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
[6,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
```

The max value of the `count` column should always be 8; I would like to insert vectors into the right locations starting with the appropriate consecutive value followed by eight trailing zeroes. The above matrices should look like this:

```
     count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
[1,]     0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0
[2,]     1 1 1 4 0 1 0 1 0
[3,]     2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
[4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
[5,]     4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
[6,]     5 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
[7,]     6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  # this row has been inserted
[8,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  # this row has been inserted
[9,]     8 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

     count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
[1,]     0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0
[2,]     1 1 1 4 0 1 0 1 0
[3,]     2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
[4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
[5,]     4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
[6,]     5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  # this row has been inserted
[7,]     6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  # this row has been inserted
[8,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
[9,]     8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  # this row has been inserted
```

The matrices are embedded in a long list, many of which already have 9 rows and do not need to be modified, so ideally this solution could be vectorized to work across the list rather than in a `for` loop. Below is some gross code to produce a toy list of 4 matrices (with the first two elements corresponding to the problematic matrices shown above).

```
list(matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,8,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,4,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0),nrow=7,ncol=9,dimnames=(list(character(0),c("count",0:7)))),matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,7,0,1,1,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,4,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0),nrow=6,ncol=9,dimnames=(list(character(0),c("count",0:7)))),matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),nrow=9,ncol=9,dimnames=(list(character(0),c("count",0:7)))),matrix(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),nrow=9,ncol=9,dimnames=(list(character(0),c("count",0:7)))))
```

This is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72986818/r-sum-across-matrix-elements-in-a-vector-that-are-of-different-dimensions) I asked recently - hopefully I can keep these matrices in a nice simple empty `list` and not have to pre-specify the `dim`s as an `array`-based solution might require. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Creating a complete matrix `m` out of the `max`imum row numbers with identical number of columns and `colnames` resp. `dimnames`, `match`  and `order`.

```
maxrow <- max(sapply(L, nrow))
colnm <- colnames(el(L))
m <- `dimnames<-`(cbind(0:(maxrow - 1L), matrix(0L, maxrow, length(colnm) - 1L)), 
             list(NULL, colnm))

lapply(L, \(x) rbind(x, m[-match(x[, 'count'], m[, 'count']), ]) |> {\(.) .[order(.[, 'count']), ]}())
# [[1]]
#      count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
# [1,]     0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0
# [2,]     1 1 1 4 0 1 0 1 0
# [3,]     2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
# [4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [5,]     4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
# [6,]     5 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
# [7,]     6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ##
# [8,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ##
# [9,]     8 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
# 
# [[2]]
#      count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
# [1,]     0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0
# [2,]     1 1 1 4 0 1 0 1 0
# [3,]     2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
# [4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [5,]     4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
# [6,]     5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ##
# [7,]     6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ##
# [8,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
# [9,]     8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  ##
# 
# [[3]]
# count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
# [1,]     0 0 2 4 0 1 0 1 0
# [2,]     1 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
# [3,]     2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [5,]     4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [6,]     5 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
# [7,]     6 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
# [8,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
# [9,]     8 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
# 
# [[4]]
#      count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
# [1,]     0 0 2 4 0 1 0 1 0
# [2,]     1 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
# [3,]     2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [5,]     4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [6,]     5 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
# [7,]     6 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
# [8,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
# [9,]     8 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

*Data:*

```
L <- list(structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(7L, 9L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("count", 
"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))), structure(c(0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(6L, 9L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("count", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))), 
    structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(9L, 9L), dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("count", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
        ))), structure(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(9L, 9L), dimnames = list(
        NULL, c("count", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
        ))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on the following idea:

1. First, create a complete matrix of *zeros* (`m`).
2. Iterate with `map2` to assign, to the matrix of zeros, each matrix of the list, considering only the rows where the columns `count` of both matrices match.

*Note:* to contemplate the case where the columns only go up to 6 (instead of 7), we redefine the matrix of zeros to have as many columns as the current matrix of the list (`.y <- .y[,1:ncol(.x)]`).

```r
library(tidyverse)

m <- matrix(0, 9, 9)
colnames(m) <- colnames(m1)
m[,1] <- 0:8

map2(mylist, rep(list(m), length(mylist)), ~ {.y <- .y[,1:ncol(.x)]; .y[.y[,1] %in% .x[,1]] <- .x; .y})

#> [[1]]
#>       count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#>  [1,]     0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0
#>  [2,]     1 1 1 4 0 1 0 1 0
#>  [3,]     2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
#>  [4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [5,]     4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
#>  [6,]     5 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
#>  [7,]     6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [8,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [9,]     8 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>       count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#>  [1,]     0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0
#>  [2,]     1 1 1 4 0 1 0 1 0
#>  [3,]     2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 2
#>  [4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [5,]     4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
#>  [6,]     5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [7,]     6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [8,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
#>  [9,]     8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>       count 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
#>  [1,]     0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0
#>  [2,]     1 1 1 4 0 1 0 1
#>  [3,]     2 1 1 2 0 2 0 1
#>  [4,]     3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [5,]     4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0
#>  [6,]     5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [7,]     6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [8,]     7 0 0 0 0 0 3 0
#>  [9,]     8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

DATA

```
list(structure(c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(7L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("count", 
"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))), structure(c(0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(6L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("count", 
"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))), structure(c(0L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = 9:8, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("count", 
"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))))
```

Comment: This is really great, thank you. I know this is annoying of me to ask and I can open a new question, but I realized that over many repeated simulations there are some matrices where the columns only go up to 6 (instead of 7). Is there a way to modify the code so that `map2` fills columns that don't match those in `m` with zero?

Comment: My solution now contemplates the case of matrices with a variable number of columns, @lamhine.

Comment: Thank you - not sure why but it's not working for me for a list of matrices with variable `ncol`s

Comment: I have just tested and it works fine. Please, check it out with the data that I have just made available and that I used.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing the data! When I set that list to `mylist` and run the code above, the `dim` of the third resulting matrix is 9x8 instead of 9x9. When you run it, are all three matrices 9x9?

Comment: Yes, the third matrix should not have 8 columns? It is a matrix whose count goes only up 6 and not up 7

Comment: I would like all the `map2`ed matrices to have uniform dimensions. It's okay though I've decided I can live with lists of 1-dimensional vectors for my current needs since they are less finicky than matrices. Would still be great to know how to get map2 to return matrices with all the same dimensions, from a list of matrices with variable rows and columns - not urgent at all though. Thank you again so much for all your help!